# Authentication error when using request npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, npm

```
var request = require('request');

request.get({
            url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json?resources=help,users,search,statuses',
            oauth: {
    consumer_key:         'Keys'
  , consumer_secret:      'are'
  , access_token:         'here'
  , access_token_secret:  ''
            }
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            var json = JSON.parse(body);console.log(body);
        });
```

I am getting "must be authenticated" error even though I have my keys in place and I'm not behind any proxy.Any ideas why?

Comment: Why not use [node-twitter-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-twitter-api)?

Comment: Can u show an equivalent method in node-twitter-api of the above call .

Comment: Well, the method you want to use is `rateLimitStatus` and then you are going to have to check out the documentation for specific use, but I can tell you that the params are going to be `(params, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, callback)` per [this](https://github.com/reneraab/node-twitter-api/blob/master/twitter.js#L935)